# Your message will be sent, but we're not quite ready

Tags: exchange, exchange-2019

I just set up an Exchange 2019 server.

Sending mail, **event to oneself**, does not work : messages are stuck in the Drafts folder with the following banner:
"Your message will be sent, but we're not quite ready, Check back in couple of minute."

[image: Message stuck as draft]

After a while the banner changes for "Something went wrong and we haven't been able to send your message yet."

Sometimes, after rebooting server, the message goes to Sent Items, but is not received in recipient's mailbox.

#### Context

Machine (Server 2022) is slow (`launchems` takes 30 secs to start), although:

- Memory (12Gb) utilized at 75%
- CPU utilization below 10%

`Get-ServerComponentState` shows everything Active except `ForwardsyncDaemon` & `ProvisioningRps`

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to DNS settings:
Set the domain controller as preferred DNS server and the leave the alternative server blank.